# CMA - Can you connect to an existing Stripe account?

Tags: isv, cma

As a follow-up to this post on [using CMA vs. COA](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275224/cma-vs-coa-for-isv-partners-which-is-better), if we use the CMA AppExchange Checkout option for processing payments, it asks to connect to a Stripe account.

If my company already has an existing Stripe account:

1. Can we connect to this existing Stripe account?
2. If "yes" to the above question, is this a good idea?  Is there potential issues or collisions that might occur with linking an existing Stripe account?

Note that our company has a whole online platform that can (and does) exist outside the Salesforce platform.

Comment: You might want to combine this question with the other one.. If you have an existing payment platform + workflow, it sounds like COA is the route for you on just that basis. CMA is probably simpler but it'll be different UX for your customers. Revenue share on COA - not sure but we doubt SF is going to "forget" to collect their share simply due to another payment channel being used.

Comment: @identigral But doesn't this increase the workload required for submitting the orders to Salesforce?  From [this trailhead on COA](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/channel-order-app-basics/appexchange_channel_orders_create), it seems like there's a long-winded process to just keep orders up to date with Salesforce.  Checkout seems to handle all this internally

Comment: You'd want to automate the order submission via [COA API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/coa_api.htm). Your payment platform does everything and then sends a complete order via API to COA.

Comment: @identigral Circled back around with the engineering team and this makes sense. They anyways would need to make adjustments, and it's easier to maintain everything in one place that's already setup. Thanks for the input here!