# What are Product Catalog and Contract Terms in Channel Order App

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, licenses, lma, pricing

We have a Second Generation Managed Package which has passed the Salesforce AppExchange Security Review and we want it to be available as paid version where the payments will be handled by ourselves using the Channel Order App (COA). So we have few doubts regarding the COA.

1. How can we associate our Managed Package to the COA?
2. When and Where can we create the Contract terms and Product Catalog, do they create automatically after the accepting Partnership Application Distribution Agreement(PADA) which comes after the Pricing Approval of Listing by Salesforce?
3. Where can we specify the details like Default Contract Length (months) and Default Billing Frequency (months) etc in Contract Terms and Pricing Type and Flat Price in Product Catalog?
4. If we want to increase the licenses for a customer, first do we need to edit the licenses in record in LMA (License Management App) and then do we need to create an Add-On Order or does creating an Add-On Order type will eventually update the license record in LMA (License Management App) to keep both LMA and COA in sync?
5. As mentioned in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/coa_import_data.htm?_ga=2.253009229.537915262.1700481028-1044803500.1700458538),  Do we need to connect the COA to the COA Production after the Pricing Approval of Listing to import the Product Catalog and Contract Terms?

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding (from dealing with a Marketing Cloud AppExchange offering):

- Questions 1 2 3 and 5 can and should all be addressed by Salesforce via cases logged in your Partners portal.  From my experience, they create the Product Catalog for your specific package/product, so reach out to them to get this moving, and making all the right connections
- Question 4: My experience is that LMA and COA are not in sync by default, so you can adjust licenses and create COA orders in either order (although they should happen one right after the other ideally)